# Problem in deriving Pauli equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I’m trying to derive the equation from the Hamiltonian

$$H=\frac{1}{m}[\vec{\sigma} \cdot (\vec p-q\vec A)]^2+ q \phi$$

and

$$[\vec{\sigma} \cdot (\vec p-q\vec A)]^2=  (\vec p-q\vec A)^2-iq \vec{\sigma} \cdot \nabla \times (\vec p-q\vec A).$$

I don’t know how the term 
$\nabla \times \vec p$ vanish in the result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using relation $\sigma_i\sigma_j=\delta_{ij}+i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$ and denotation $P_i=p_i-eA_i$, we can write
$$(\sigma_iP_i)(\sigma_jP_j)=\delta_{ij}P_iP_j+i\epsilon_{ijk}P_iP_j\sigma_k,$$
where the last term explicitly is
$$P_iP_j=p_ip_j-ep_iA_j-eA_ip_j+e^2A_iA_j.$$
Due to $\epsilon_{ijk}p_ip_j=0$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}A_iA_j=0$, you should find
$$-i\epsilon_{ijk}p_iA_j\sigma_k-i\epsilon_{ijk}A_ip_j\sigma_k\rightarrow+(\nabla\times {\bf A})\cdot\sigma=\sigma\cdot{\bf H}.$$

In your notation, you should see that
$$\nabla\times{\bf p}=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jp_k=-i\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j\partial_k,$$
which goes to zero due to the fact that ${\bf v}\times{\bf v}=0$, where ${\bf v}$ is arbitrary vector.

Comment: What is the motivation for the Hamiltonian that you start with?

Comment: @my2cts it’s the Hamiltonian of a charged particle in a magnetic field.

Comment: Do you have a reference? I notice that it has no rest mass and no kinetic energy .

Comment: @my2cts I just use part of hamiltonian

Comment: Part of which Hamiltonian? A reference would be helpful.

Comment: @my2cts I do not understand what do you want to see. Starting from fermion field, you can derive its hamiltonian as $T^{00}$ component of stress-energy tensor, $H=\alpha m+\beta m$, where $\alpha = \gamma^0\gamma$, $\beta=\gamma^0$ and $\gamma$ is the vector of three $\gamma$-matrices. Then, your are interested in solutions of $i\partial_t\psi=H\psi$ in non-relativistic limit. The full non-relativisitic hamiltonian is $H=({\bf p}-e{\bf A})^2/(2m)-e\sigma\cdot{\bf H}/(2m)+eA_0$.